# Select node with unique id using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I select a specific node with an unique ID and return the entire node as xml.

```
<xml>
<library>
<book id='1'>
<title>firstTitle</title>
<author>firstAuthor</author>
</book>
<book id='2'>
<title>secondTitle</title>
<author>secondAuthor</author>
</book>
<book id='3'>
<title>thirdTitle</title>
<author>thirdAuthor</author>
</book>
</library>
</xml>
```

In this case I would like to return book with id='3', so it will look something like this:

```
<book id='3'>
<title>thirdTitle</title>
<author>thirdAuthor</author>
</book>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/book[@id='3']" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform your sample input document to the stated sample output document

Comment: How to do this if id is the attribute of the current element?

Comment: Make your question a separate question in Stackoverflow.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673341/how-to-select-element-by-attribute-with-xslt

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) (because you are searching in the document, not transforming it), that would be:

```
//book[@id=3]
```

Of course, depending on your language, there might be a library that makes this search even simpler.

Comment: Thinking again, maybe `//book[@id='3']` is more appropriate. I'm not sure about the fine details, but will work in more cases (for example, when the IDs are not numbers)

Answer (score 3):

The most performant* and readable way to do it is via a `key`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- To match your expectation and input (neither had <?xml?> -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- Create a lookup for books -->
    <!-- (match could be more specific as well if you want: "/xml/library/book") -->
    <xsl:key name="books" match="book" use="@id" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Lookup by key created above. -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('books', 3)" />
        <!-- You can use it anywhere where you would use a "//book[@id='3']" -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

** For 2142 items and 121 lookups it made 500 milliseconds difference, which was a 33% overall speedup in my case. Measured against `//book[@id = $id-to-look-up]`.*

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT you use `xsl:copy-of` to insert a selected node set into the output result tree:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/*/library/book[@id=3]"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

take a look at SimpleXML xpath

[xpath simpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)