# How to select element by attribute with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml file:

```
<writer id_writer="1">
  <name>name</name>
</writer>

<film id_writer="1">
</film>
```

How to print the writer of each film using xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="film">
   <xsl:value-of select="writer[@id_writer='what to put here']/name"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient way to resolve cross references like this in XSLT is generally to use a *key*.  The key definition goes at the top level of your stylesheet, outside any templates, and specifies which nodes you want to retrieve and how to compute the identifying key value for each one

```
<xsl:key name="writerById" match="writer" use="@id_writer" />
```

Once the key is defined you can retrieve matching nodes by key value using a function

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('writerById', @id_writer)/name"/>
```

Some XSLT processors (notably recent versions of Saxon EE) will automatically optimise `//writer[@id_writer = current()/@id_writer]` predicates to execute as efficiently as the explicit key-based approach, but this is not something you can necessarily rely on if you are using an older or less sophisticated processor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to relate `film` and `writer` by their attributes, so try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="film">
    <xsl:value-of select="../writer[@id_writer=current()/@id_writer]/name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: `../writer` rather than just `writer` - they're siblings, not parent and child.

Comment: Thanks, @IanRoberts .. Little over confidence that I didn't test it :)

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your 'what to put here' is

```
current()/@id_writer
```

However this is not the only thing needed to make it work, as the writer node is not part of the film node's tree. A complete working answer based on your question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/body">
        <xsl:for-each select="film">
            <xsl:value-of select="/body/writer[@id_writer=current()/@id_writer]/name"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Complete XML to feed this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <writer id_writer="1">
        <name>name</name>
    </writer>

    <film id_writer="1">
    </film>
</body>
```

Working example here: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Ck

Comment: Please make sure that your answer contains the same code as your working example. Your working example really works, your code here does not.

Comment: I tried to answer only the exact question, being 'what to put here'. But I've now edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Before you edited the answer, there was no `/body/` in front of the path expression - and it would have led nowhere.